# Android CallLog.Calls provider query problem

Tags: android, provider

I am trying to get call log by using the CallLog.Calls content provider. However, I am little lost about the query I need to make. I am able to make a query and load the result in a ListView. But the query return all types of call.

Of course I can use a switch-case and take appropriate action as per the types of call returned. But for my program I only need the outgoing call logs.

So, how do I modify the query to get only outgoing call types. (I believe I have to use CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE somewhere?). I have tried to modify the query in various ways but I keep getting error. If I try to supply the CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE as an selection arg I get an error as its an int type and the query looks for String type.

I may be missing something simple, but can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You. Here's my query below,

```
getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, ORDER_BY );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                      CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=?",
                                      new String[] { String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE) },
                                      ORDER_BY);
```